# ¿Se documenta «mejunje» en el ámbito culinario?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, comida

En casa hacemos una pasta untable a base de mezclar un bote de guacamole ya hecho (de los pequeños, unos 200 gramos) con un par de latas de atún en escabeche, y al resultado lo llamamos "el mejunje". Sin embargo, hoy me ha dado por buscar el significado de *mejunje* y me encuentro con esto:

> **[mejunje](https://dle.rae.es/mejunje)**
>
> Del ár. hisp. *mamzúǧ*, y este del ár. clás. *mamzūǧ* 'mezclado'.
>
> 1. m. Cosmético o medicamento formado por la mezcla de varios ingredientes.

Vaya, parece que la palabra no se usa para comidas, de hecho su significado me parece cercano al de *[potingue](https://dle.rae.es/potingue)*. Sin embargo, veo algunos usos en la literatura en el ámbito culinario. Véanse algunos ejemplos:

> *La diputada Anna Balletbó agradeció la copa de champaña conmemorativa del décimo aniversario, "en vez del mejunje habitual de naranja" [...].*
>
> El País, 01/06/1984 : El puente de los vuelos perdidos (España).

> *Llegó un gendarme con dos vasos de cristal llenos de un líquido espeso y negro. "¿Café?", les preguntó. "¡Oh, sí! Merci...!" Los dos muchachos aceptaron y se bebieron de un sorbo, sin pestañear, aquel mejunje.*
>
> José María Gironella, "Un millón de muertos", 1961 (España).

Entiendo que su uso en el ámbito culinario parece, pues, despectivo dado que en ambos casos se compara la bebida con algo de mal sabor (como un medicamento). De hecho, la primera acepción de *potingue*, mencionada anteriormente, es precisamente "bebida de botica o de aspecto y sabor desagradable", por lo que es posible que en ambos casos se hubiera preferido usar *potingue* antes que *mejunje*. O incluso *[brebaje](https://dle.rae.es/brebaje)*, que también hace referencia a bebidas, "en especial la compuesta de ingredientes desagradables al paladar".

Así pues, ¿se usa *mejunje* en el ámbito culinario de forma habitual, aunque sea de forma despectiva? ¿O es su uso anecdótico y posiblemente se prefiriera otra palabra en los casos en que aparece?

Comment: Los mayores de mi familia usaban esa palabra para describir cualquier revoltura o mezcla de cosas obteniendo como resultado algo "comestible".

Answer (score 4):

Acá en Chile lo he escuchado como "menjunje" y es de uso poco habitual, coloquial, ligeramente despectivo pero no para describir algo de mal sabor si no más bien una mezcla indefinida de ingredientes. Esta mezcla podría ser algún tipo de pasta en el ámbito culinario pero también puede referirse a preparaciones para otros usos (médicos, estéticos).

En el [Diccionario de americanismos de la ASALE](https://www.asale.org/damer/menjunje) aparece más o menos con esa acepción pero no menciona su uso en Chile.

> I. 1.  m. *Mx, Bo, Py.* Ingrediente o elemento de una preparación. pop.
> 2. *Bo, Ur.* Comida rápida, elaborada con productos baratos y poco nutritivos. pop.